# iOS Streaming : timedmetadata not returning the entire value

Tags: ios, avplayer, audio-streaming, icecast, avplayeritem

Trying to play an live audio stream in which I am observing the "timedMetadata"
The normal data items are getting retrieved such as the content title and url..But there is some extra data coming as part of the ICEcast which is basically for playback of Ads.This data however is visible in Charles is not getting populated in AVMetadataItem

```
for (AVMetadataItem *data in item.timedMetadata) {
    NSLog(@"Identifier : %@",data.identifier);
    NSLog(@"Value : %@",data.value);
    NSLog(@"Datatype : %@",data.dataType);
}
```

Am I missing something here?The same data is retrievable in Matt's AudioStreamer classes.Can it be done via AVPlayer?Is it coming under a different observer?
1. How can I get this data?

```
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
self.songPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
CALayer *superlayer = self.playerView.layer;

AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.songPlayer];
[playerLayer setFrame:self.playerView.bounds];
playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
[superlayer addSublayer:playerLayer];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[self.songPlayer currentItem]];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:0 context:nil];
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:0 context:nil];
```

2. what are the different observers available for the AVPlayer?